# How to properly define services in compose file

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose

I have to run simple service on Docker Compose. The first image is to host the previously created service while the second image, which is dependent on the first one, is to run the tests. So I created `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM python:2.7-slim
WORKDIR /flask
COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . .
CMD ["python", "routes.py"]
```

Everything works. I created some simple tests, which also works, and placed the file in the same directory as `routes.py`.
So I tried to create `docker-compose.yml` file and did something like that:

```
version: '2'
services:
    app:
        build: .
        command: 'python MyTest.py'
        ports:
            - "5000:5000"
    tests:
        build:
            context: Mytest.py
        depends_on:
            - app
```

When I run it I received an error:

```
TypeError: You must specify a directory to build in path
[13341] Failed to execute script docker-compose
```

So how should I specify these directory and where I can place it in `app` or `tests` service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> TypeError: You must specify a directory to build in path
>   [13341] Failed to execute script docker-compose

Above error tells you `context:` should be folder to put your Dockerfile, but as you seems could use the same image to test your product, I think no need to specify it.

And I guess your `MyTest.py` will visit `5000` port of your app container to have a test. So what you needed is next:

```
version: '2'
services:
  app:
    build: .
    container_name: my_app
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
  tests:
    build: .
    depends_on:
      - app
    command: python MyTest.py
```

Here, what you need to pay attention is: you should visit `http://my_app:5000` for your test in `MyTest.py`.

Meanwhile, in `MyTest.py` suggest you to `sleep` some time, because `depends_on` just can ensure `tests` start after `app`, but cannot assure at that time your flask already ready, you can also consider [this](https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/) to assure the order.

Comment: Of course your solution works, but I get an error `Cannot start service app: b'driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint challenge (...): Bind for 0.0.0.0:5000 failed: port is already allocated' It may be caused by not sleep some time in `MyTest.py`?
`

Comment: It seems your host already use `5000` port, use `sudo netstat -oanltp | grep 5000`  on host to confirm it, all just change to `6000:5000` to have a quick check.

Comment: Just solved it. I have a container, which uses `5000` port and just stopped it. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify `dockerfile` field as you are using `version-2` docker compose.

Check [this](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#build) out.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your build command:

```
...
  build:
    context: .
    dockerfile: Dockerfile
...
```